# Memory remapping solution failed, only 3 GB usable out of 8 GB

Tags: windows-7, memory, graphics-card, cpu, motherboard

I tried remapping my memory to [fix the 3 GB of RAM problem](https://superuser.com/questions/705556/how-to-manually-allocate-memory-to-system) but it failed.

Basically this is my problem: I've tried doing memory remapping but it half-works. It goes from this:

- Total: 8192 MB
- Appropriated: 896 MB
- Available: 3200 MB

To this:

- Total: 8192 MB
- Appropriated: 0 MB
- Available: 8192 MB

**Now as you can tell:** Since no memory is appropriated for the system, none of the core processes have any RAM to function!

**This is proven:** When I start up Windows, all I get is a blank screen! It goes from Starting Windows and then it hangs and then it goes to black screen and stays there

**When I turn off Memory Remapping:** It actually boots up

#### System Info

- OS: Windows 7 64-Bit Professional
- RAM: DDR2 PC2-6400 800 MHz, 200 pin
- 2 GB of RAM × 4 sticks, only 4 RAM Slots
- ASUS P5W DH DELUXE motherboard
- EVGA graphics: NVidia GTX 650 (Super Clocked Edition)
- HDD: Toshiba 1 TB
- CPU: Intel 2 Core Duo E4500 @ 2.20 GHz / 2.22 GHz (Turbo clocked)

#### BIOS

```
AMIBIOS:
Version: 3001 /// Build Date: 10/22/09
PROCESSOR:
Type: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E4500 @ 2.20 GHz /// Speed: 2200 MHz /// Count: 2
```

#### Common answers

- I'm using Windows x64, so it's not a 32-bit limitation
- Multiple settings changes in `msconfig` had no effect.
- I've disabled that as well as re-enabled PAE to no avail.
- The motherboard is confirmed to support 8GB by both the web site and the manual
- *Windows 7 needs to be verified: **It has been.**
- The motherboard BIOS has been updated to the latest available version
- I have tried three RAM kits; it's *highly unlikely* that they are all broken.
- POST reports all 8GB of RAM present and accounted for.
- The RAM has been seated in multiple configurations with each stick in each motherboard slot.
- BIOS RAM configuration: **PC2-6400 and 1.9 Volts**
- [Link to the motherboard manual](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/socket775/P5W%20DH%20Deluxe/e2557_p5w_dh_dlx.pdf)

Comment: Good lord, the tone of this question is unabashedly hostile.  Why would anyone volunteering their time here see something like this and think to themself, "This is the person upon whom I should spend some of my time; they seem to have quite a constructive attitude"?

Comment: @DopeGhoti Sorry can you please answer it now? Its just that when I was writing this I was very angry. I have literally, no lie, spent 75 SOLID hours trying to fix this problem and its annoying me quite bitterly. I am sorry but It's been very annoying and I've got a head ache trying to fix this. And what annoys me more is that no one else seems to have this problem.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Sorry forgot to mention I also edited out the angry bits. Its been quite a **fun** 75 hours fixing this. Also because I've bought $450 in RAM trying to fix this RAM. It started out with buying expensively nice new ram which didn't work because I misread the DDR2 for DDR3, then the new DDR2 RAM I bought didn't work, and I've just bought a complete set of RAM. And also while adding a new hard drive I had 3 hard drives burn because the wire was put in wrong.

Comment: Thank you for editing the question.  Unfortunately, I don't have a magic answer for you, but do have a couple of ideas that might point you in the right direction.  Have you tried booting Windows in Safe Mode, or enabling Boot Logging to see where the boot process ends?  Have you tried a Linux LiveCD just to ensure that *any* OS can boot and use all the RAM? Have you used a tool like Memtest86 to check the RAM?

Comment: @DopeGhoti Thank you! :D If I had any points I would upvote. I haven't tried that yet, but once I'm able to get back to my PC I'll try

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I got the information from BIOS >>> Sytem Information. And I also turned on memory mapping from the BIOS. I don't know if there's another method to activating the mapping from outside of BIOS but feel free to suggest.

Comment: The one last thing I would try to see if it works is do a [sysprep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysprep) before you toggle the setting. From a administrative command prompt in the `C:\windows\System32\sysprep` folder do the command `sysprep /generalize /shutdown` and it should shut off your computer when it is done, after it finshes toggle the setting and let windows start up and re-initize it's hardware and see if that works (you should take a backup before trying just in case)

Comment: You could have a bad RAM slot. Have you tried to test your RAM using something like [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/)? I don't see that in your common answers section. :-)

Comment: Actually it is my common answers "I have tried three RAM kits; it's highly unlikely that they are all broken" 3 sets of 4 sticks of RAM, I have tried each and everyone, rearranging them in the DIMM slots, every combination of 1 to 2 sticks of RAM. So I entrust that the RAM would be fine.

Comment: But what you're trying to investigate with the RAM test is if one of the DIMM slots is bad. You would do that by testing each one individually. Since you have known good RAM sticks, put one on DIMM0, test it using Memtest86+ at least 2 times, remove and place in DIMM1, and repeat until all slots/banks are tested. I didn't see that in your list. We're not really testing the RAM but the slots being used by the RAM.